# Can a PI emulate a CD/RW drive

Tags: usb, otg

I have a piece of software that archives out onto CD and I really want to remove the drive as I am just archiving the data and copying it back off the disk onto my computer and putting the CD in the safe.

A search turned up [this on Tindie](https://www.tindie.com/products/gigatron/piso-versatile-flash-drive-cd-emulator/) and some code on GITHUB but these are both just CD emulators.

Due to the age of the software, I cannot get a newer version or the code changed so this feels like my only option as the program will not write to a USB stick but is happy to use a USB CD writer!

I tried a CD emulator emulator and even running the program in a VM (with the drive linking to a file) but these did not work - the software just asks for a disk to be inserted.

What I wonder is if it is possible to turn a PI (esp a PI Zero) into a writable CD drive (or rewritable drive) that I can move from one computer to another using the OTG abilities?

Comment: I don't understand what you actually need. You want to backup data from your PC to a CD? And what does that have to do with a Pi? The Pi has no CD drive, and any storage (be it an external USB disk, SD-Card or whatever) that can be plugged into the Pi can be plugged into the PC as well.

Comment: @PMF it appears that the OP needs a fake CD burner because a proprietary program uses it to store backups and will not use any other device

Comment: @jsotola Correct - the program will only use a CD drive and I want to replace that with a Pi.

Comment: Have you considered to use another/better program?

Comment: @ingo The cost (esp in current climate) is significant and involves changing a fair number of processes so training impact is great as well.